# JavaScript: How to check if exactly 4 out of 5 items are the same in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Good day,

I am trying to create a dice poker browser game. The problem that I am having is that I can't seem to figure out how to check the results after a round efficiently.

So far I have come up with a switch statement which checks if there is a case of "five of a kind". If so, return something, if not continue.

```
const getResult = diceArr => {

    // Create an array with only the numbers
    let dice1 = diceArr[0].randomNum;
    let dice2 = diceArr[1].randomNum;
    let dice3 = diceArr[2].randomNum;
    let dice4 = diceArr[3].randomNum;
    let dice5 = diceArr[4].randomNum;
    diceArray = [];
    diceArray.push(dice1, dice2, dice3, dice4, dice5);

    // Check the result using a switch statement. Start at the highest rank. If encountered, stop checking.
    let result;
    switch(result) {
        case diceArray[0] === diceArray[1] === diceArray[2] === diceArray[3] === diceArray[4] :
            console.log('5 of a kind!');
            break;
        // case ? -> No idea where to go from here
    }
}
```

What would be an efficient way of checking if exactly 4 out of 5 items in the array are the same?(4 of a kind)

Also, is a switch statement a good way to solve a problem like this?

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You could create a `counter` object which will have each `randomNum` as key and the number of times it appears as value. Then, check if the `counter` has 4 as value using [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
const counter = diceArr.reduce((acc, o) => {
  acc[o.randomNum] = acc[o.randomNum] + 1 || 1;
  return acc
}, {})

const isFourOfAKind = Object.values(counter).includes(4);
console.log(isFourOfAKind)
```

Comment: Thanks! I can definitely build on this.

Answer (score 2):

This function returns `true` if there are four cards with the same value:

```
function areThereFourSameCards(cards) {
  const groups = cards.reduce((acc, card) => {
    acc[card] = (acc[card] + 1) || 1;
    return acc;
  }, {});

  Object.keys(groups).some(k => groups[k] === 4)
}
```

Can be generalised to match different values.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have already checked whether all items are equal or not hence I will give you a hint to check equality exactly for the four items in your case:

```
function checkEqualityForFour(){
  var diceArray=new Array(2,2,1,2,2);
  for(var i=0;i<=1;i++){ //we have to check equality of 4 among 5 values
    var count=1;
    for(var j=i+1;j<diceArray.length;j++){
       if(diceArray[i]==diceArray[j])
         count++;
   }
    if(count==4)
     return true;
  }
   return false;
}


console.log(checkEqualityForFour());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.reduce()` to create an object holding the number of occurrences of each element. Then iterate over it to check if an item is occurred 4 times.

```js
var diceArr = new Array(5).fill(0).map((item) => Math.floor(6*Math.random())+1); // Fill array with random numbers

console.log(diceArr);

var repeatings = diceArr.reduce((acc, item) => {
    if (!acc[item]){
      acc[item] = 0;
    }
    acc[item]++
    return acc
}, {} )

console.log(repeatings);

var repating4times = Object.keys(repeatings).find((key) => repeatings[key] == 4)

console.log(repating4times);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to confirm that an element appears exactly 4 times in an array. That is 4 elements of the same kind out of 5.

This particular case comes with some limitations that would make solution easier.

Because we need 4 elements out of 5 to be the same
 - you can only have two different elements in the array

This means you don't even have to check all the items. Only the first two will suffice.

A naive approach you could go with that would work pretty well because you're working with such small datasets would be a simple greedy algorithm.

You want to take the first two elements and traverse the whole array to see if either one exists three more times in the array. Remember our limitations above. To make the job easier, having a nice function to help count how many times an element appears in an array would be nice.

```
function countEntries(item, array) {
  let count = 0

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if (item === array[i])
      count++;
  }

  return count
}
```

That function does exactly that and is very easy to understand. Now for the main solution:

```
function oneOfAKind(results) {
  let result
  let isOneOfAKind = false

  for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    const item = results[i]

    const itemCount = countEntries(item, results)
    if (itemCount === 4) {
      result = item
      isOneOfAKind = true
      break
    }
  }

  return [isOneOfAKind, result]
}
```

So this function returns an array containing a boolean and a number. If the array contains a "one of a kind" element, it returns an array containing true, and the one of a kind element.

Let's test it:

```
const diceResults = [4, 3, 3, 3, 3]
oneOfAKind(diceResults)

// returns [true, 3]
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Let `arr=[1,1,1,1,2]` be my array

Try

<s>`new Set(arr.map(x=>x.toString())).size`</s>

```
 if(arr.toString().split(arr[0]).length==5 || arr.toString().split(arr[1]).length==5)
    console.log('Exactly 4 matches')
```

Comment: And what about [1,1,2,2,2]

Comment: As mentioned in your deleted answer, this will return 2 for `[1,1,2,2,2]`  as well

Comment: Oh i see.  I didn't consider a test case like this. Thank you for adding.

Comment: @Andreas I just fixed it, and that map was to just stringify the array elements.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like below

```
const getResult = diceArr => {

    // Create an array with only the numbers
    let dice1 = diceArr[0].randomNum;
    let dice2 = diceArr[1].randomNum;
    let dice3 = diceArr[2].randomNum;
    let dice4 = diceArr[3].randomNum;
    let dice5 = diceArr[4].randomNum;
    diceArray = [];
    diceArray.push(dice1, dice2, dice3, dice4, dice5);
    diceCheck = {}
    diceArray.forEach((item)=>{
      diceCheck[item] = diceCheck[item] || 0;
      diceCheck[item] += 1;
    });
    if(Object.keys(diceCheck).length == 2){
      console.log("Voila");
    }

}
```