# How to find out if an array has n equal numbers?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to write a function to find out if an array has n items. My previous approach was to find all the individual values of an input array, and count the amount of times those individual items are included in the array. If the amount of times an item is repeated is greater than or equal to n, it will return true. The problem is that this approach is inefficient for large arrays with a length of around 50 (o(n^2) time) since I will be using this code for tens of thousands of iterations.

Here is the code I tried:

```
function isSameItems(n, array) {
    let vals = [];

    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        let arrayItem = array[i];

        if (!vals.includes(arrayItem)) {
            vals.push(arrayItem);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
        let valsItem = vals[i];
        let itemCounter = 0;

        for (j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {   
            if (array[j] == valsItem) itemCounter += 1;

            if (itemCounter >= n) return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

How can I rewrite this function such that I am not searching through every object in the array, for every individual item in the array?

Comment: `[2, 4, 4, 2, 4, 19] // true the array has 3 twos which are equal items`. How? It has 3 `fours` not `twos`

Comment: My mistake, I will update the question.

Comment: Please add the code you've tried.

Comment: And do you want to check if something is repeated *at least 3 times* or *exactly 3 times* ?

Comment: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have had no ideas so far on how to solve this problem such that it works in the cases shown above, I am currently looking for a snippet of code that can give a correct output given the 3 arrays.

Comment: you should try something, and then if stuck then ask for solution.

Comment: @adiga I want to check if something is repeated exactly 3 times.

Comment: can there be multiple elements repeated 3 times? will 3+ repetition be taken as true?

Comment: [JavaScript: How to check if exactly 4 out of 5 items are the same in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59500031/3082296)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an object to get count of each element and then check if any of the count is equal to given no of times using `some()`

```js
function haveSameItems(arr, n){
  let countObj = {};
  for(let a of arr){
    countObj[a] = (countObj[a] || 0) + 1;
  }
  return Object.values(countObj).some(count => count >= n)
}

console.log(haveSameItems([1, 1, 3, 5, 1], 3));
console.log(haveSameItems([10, 39, 201, 2] , 3));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a map and store for each entry the number, how often it was in there.
Then check if some entry in the map has a number of 3.

```js
const map = new Map();

[2, 4, 4, 2, 4, 19].forEach(entry => {
    if (map.has(entry)) {
        const currentCount = map.get(entry);
        map.set(entry, currentCount + 1);
    } else {
        map.set(entry, 1);
    }
});

map.forEach((value, key) => {
    if (value >= 3) {
        console.log(key, " has more has ", value, " entries");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write some logic like this:

```js
function checkEqual(arr) {
  let tempObj = {};
  arr.forEach((item) => {
    if(tempObj[item]) {
      tempObj[item]++;
    } else {
      tempObj[item] = 1;
    }
  });
  // now check exactly for 3 occurrances
  return Object.values(tempObj).includes(3);
}

console.log(checkEqual([1, 1, 3, 5, 1])) // true, the array has 3 ones which are equal items

console.log(checkEqual([2, 4, 4, 2, 4, 19])); // true the array has 3 fours which are equal items

console.log(checkEqual([10, 39, 201, 2]));
```

Comment: nesting `forEach`, `find` and `includes` seems like a really bad approach. A simple counter object and then checking if the object has value equal to 3 should be enough

Comment: @adiga made my code more simpler and optimal